# Display submitted Form Data in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, webview

I've been trying to display submitted form data into a div below the form. Without refreshing the page. I have multiple forms with a div under each one I would like to insert the text into the div below that form.

Heres a jsfiddle of what my forms div look like : http://jsfiddle.net/LNBhj/

Part of my html code (I have multiple forms with divs under each one like this):

```
<div style='float:left'>
<form action='demo_form.asp'>
    <input type='text' name='email' value="+object_guid+" id='guid' style='display:none'>
        <input type='text' name='email' id='page' style='font-size: 200%;width:78%;float:left'>
            <input type='submit' onclick='goToPage();' value='>>' style='float:right;width:20%;font-size: 200%'>
    </div>
<div style='float:left;height:50px;width:400px;border:2px solid black'>Have submitted form text display above this text</div>
```

Comment: dear friend, I can see the type of the ">>" is submit, So the form will be submitted to 'demo_form.asp', considering if  'demo_form.asp' is same page, then better you can use the server side help, one more thing please name your form, Secondly, if you want the form it be ajax posted, then displaying the posted values in the div will be easier. Consider your choice.

Comment: I'm already processing it server side and wanted to display it client side white the server is processing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have worked to an extent, giving you an idea,

1. Correct your html, missing ,
2. convert your 'submit' to 'button' type.
3. Remove your onclick functions.

Have shown the working example for top two forms,

when you fill the data and click on the form, the

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=button]").click(function(){
        var myChildren = $(this).parent().children();
        var $submited='';
        $(myChildren).each(function(i, obj){
            if(myChildren.eq(i).is(":visible")){
            $submited += ($(this).parent().children().eq(i).val())+', ';             
            }

        });       
        $submited = $submited.substr(0, ($submited.length - 4));
        $(this).parent().next('div').html($submited);
        //Ajax Functionality goes here
        $.get('demo_form.asp', function(data){
            //rest operation to carry out at client side.
        })

    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LNBhj/2/)

**Check out the Top two forms, by filling the values and click on the button**

For ajax functionality, you can refer http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/, Simple